# Web server to run an executable binary using Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'd like to create a web server which serves REST APIs. Most of the functionality on the server side already exists in an executable binary or some shell script. So instead of rewriting this functionality in the API, the REST API is just a thin layer which calls the executable binary and returns the response. I'd like to try to use Heroku for this, but open to other options as well. A few questions:

1. Does Heroku allow me to deploy an executable binary and run it as part of an API request?
2. Does Heroku provide a local execution environment for things such as temp files?